# MacOs monterey Zsh killed : ls

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos-monterey

Why does Mac OS Monterey killing all process in the terminal, even open terminal and write
ls then is show every-time.
zsh: killed     ls
same goes for some other commands like " ./gradlew uploadArchives", but all other commands like git is working fine that means Brew is installed and working.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue in my Mac M1, I found that the path added using the path_helper was causing the issue in the file "/etc/zprofile".

I commented out

```
#if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
#   eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
#fi
```

Then added my own export PATH line

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all homebrew packages

Ran homebrew uninstall script to completely uninstall homebrew itself

Reinstalled homebrew

Reinstalled packages I want

Installed zsh via homebrew

ran `chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/zsh`

Opened new terminal

Issue is gone.

Comment: i did the same but issue is still there

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's some extra-pedantic thing I did which turns out to have been necessary. This may be a useful resource: https://vineethbharadwaj.medium.com/m1-mac-switching-terminal-between-x86-64-and-arm64-e45f324184d9

Answer (score -1):

Please execute this line of command in the terminal
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}
export PATH

However, this is only a temporary effect, and it will not work when you close the terminal.

So you need to go through the open .bash_profile
Add the above settings to the end of the file, and don't forget to edit and save them
source .bash_profile
Then turn off the terminal, open the command again, and you're good to go